# SQLBulkCopyOptions violation when not specified

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk

Lately I encountered a problem using SQL bulk insert, there was a check constraint on a varchar column of the table I was bulk inserting to.

The error that occurred was "Bulk insert error - This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction"

After some fiddling around I came across a solution setting the SQLBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints flag on the options fixed the problem.

The thing is I don't understand why this fixes it, the data being copied in had no violation of the check constraint and by default the Check Constraints option is turned off.
So it should not report a violation.

Any light shed on this matter would sure be appreciated.